# How to identify an element in a table whatever its place

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, axios

Here is the new script with the find function which allows me to identify a single element of the array for sure but there is still a small problem. As you can see it's my const crypto which contains the data I want to display on the front end. However when I want to call crypto at the return level the const is not recognized.

Hello again,

I updated the script now it works I can display on the front end the data I want however I have the impression that the request to the api is executed several times when I would like there to be only one request

I put below a screen of the console.log of my script.
As you can see the data requested is displayed first as undefined then it is displayed several times, then I put blocked due to the too large number of requests made in little time

[image]

Thanks for your help

How do I make my requests :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://localhost:4500/coingeckotest")
.then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json()
  }
  throw response;
})
.then(data => {
  setData(data)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error("Error fetching data: ", error)
  setError(error)
})
.finally(() => {
  setLoading(false)
})
}, [])

const uniswap = data&&data[0].tickers?.find(donne => 
donne.trade_url === 'https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap? 
inputCurrency=0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599&
outputCurrency=ETH')
const uniprice = uniswap?.converted_last?.usd
const sushiswap = data&&data[1].tickers?.find(donne => 
donne.trade_url === 'https://app.sushi.com/swap? 
inputCurrency=0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c59
9&outputCurrency=ETH')
const sushiprice = sushiswap?.converted_last?.usd
const curvefinance = data&&data[2].tickers?.find(donne => 
donne.base === 'DAI')
const curveprice = curvefinance?.converted_last?.usd
const quickswap = data&&data[3].tickers?.find(donne => 
donne.trade_url === 'https://quickswap.exchange/#/swap? 
inputCurrency=0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf127
0&outputCurrency=0xbbba073c31bf03b8acf7c28ef0738decf369
5683')
const quickprice = quickswap?.converted_last?.usd
console.log(uniprice)
console.log(sushiprice)
console.log(curveprice)
console.log(quickprice)
if (loading) return "Loading..."
if(error) return "Error !"

 return (
 <>
 </>
 )
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find out the first entry that matches a particular coin_id. The code for that would be:

```
const desiredCoinID = "something"; (determined by some user input)
const desiredCoinObject = data.find(coin => coin.coin_id === desiredCoinID);
const priceInUSD = desiredCoinObject?.tickers?.converted_last?.usd;
```

——-Updated Answer——-

Hi, this is my answer to your updated question. const crypto that you use is available only within the scope of the callback of the useEffect function, which is why you cannot see the results on your screen. There are two ways you can go about it:

First, you can declare crypto as a let outside the useEffect and then update it inside your useEffect. That way your crypto will have global scope. But there is a better way to do this, which is to use the useState hook.

You can declare a crypto, setCrypto using useState and then use the setter to update the value if crypto inside useEffect after the data fetching is over. Let me know if you need help writing code.

Comment: I still have a small problem to display on the front end. My const is not recognized in 'return'.

Comment: My script : function App() {
const url = 'http://localhost:4500/test';
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
   if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
   }
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    const cryptotest = data[0].tickers?.find(element => element.trade_url === 'https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?inputCurrency=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48&outputCurrency=ETH')
    const pricecryptotest = cryptotest.converted_last.usd
    console.log(pricecryptotest)
  })
}, [])
return (
  );
}

Comment: It'd be great if you could just add this code below your question as an edit, I am finding it really hard to understand this.

Comment: Good to hear it all worked out!

Comment: Do you have any idea why it doesn't recognize the 'crypto' const in the return ?

Comment: I would again request you to make add your most recent comment to the bottom of the post as an edit so that I can take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I updated the post with my new problem, thanks for your patience

Comment: Hello, I added the answer to the bottom of my previous answer. Also, please keep in my mind when updating your original question, do not remove the original question, just mention the follow-up as an edit below the original one. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know about the modification of the posts thanks for the information, I updated my script and I put you a picture with an explanation the last problem I encounter 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you combine the two .then blocks into one .then, so that you use setState inside the first .then itself. _setState(response.json())_

Comment: But why are so many queries made automatically?

Comment: The useEffect runs once when the component mount is finished, inside it, you set the state of the function. This causes a re-render, hence a re-mount and the useEffect runs again. This forces the setter to run again. Now, if the same value were to be passed to the setter, there won't be a re-render, but it seems that is not the case, which is why we are in a endless loop of useEffect running.

Comment: But if I don't make an error, we can see in the console.log that they are the same values, right? But how to make useEffect execute only once from the moment it received a value 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Lets try one thing, we will run the fetch only if data is not defined, so try adding an if check at the beginning like follows: ***if(data) return;***

Comment: like this ?  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) return;
    fetch("http://localhost:4500/coingecko")

Comment: For the moment it seems to me that the problem is solved, I added at the beginning an if(data === null) and I removed the strict react mode, what do you think?

Comment: Oh yess, react strict mode causes double renders, but your fetch was being called more than twice right?

Comment: Indeed since I don't use the strict mode anymore it reduces the number of requests. Now I have 4 requests so useEffect doesn't execute in a loop but 4 times so I have a little trouble to understand why